# Can't call speak() of the TextToSpeech instance directly

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I'll add the code first.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextToSpeech myTTS;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnSpeak = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }
        });
        myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {
            public void onInit(int arg0) {}
        });


        myTTS.speak("Why doesn't this work?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        speakOut();     // why doesn't this work either???
    }
    private void speakOut() {
        myTTS.speak("Why does this work?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myTTS.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with a TextToSpeech instance.

When I click on the button, it speaks.

However when I call speak() method directly with the TextToSpeech instance, it doesn't speak at all.

Calling speakOut() method which is called when the button is clicked doesn't work either.

I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextToSpeech` constructor initiates connection with the service, which is in another process.  The TTS object you create is not usable until the connection is established.  The status of the connection is reported in the `onInit()` method of the listener.  You need to retain the status reported there to know when the service is available for use.

I reworked your example a little and added log statements to demonstrate the behavior.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Demo";

    TextToSpeech myTTS;
    boolean mInitComplete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnSpeak = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut("You pressed the button");
            }
        });
    }

    private void speakOut(String msg) {
        if (mInitComplete) {
            int status = myTTS.speak(msg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                Log.i(TAG, "speakOut(): SUCCESS");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "speakOut(): ERROR");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "speakOut(): TTS Not Initialized");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume()");

        myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    mInitComplete = true;
                    Log.i(TAG, "onInit(): TTS Initialized");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onInit(): TTS Init Failed");
                }
            }
        });

        speakOut("This will fail because TTS init is not complete");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");

        myTTS.shutdown();
        mInitComplete = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got your point, I should read this twice. By the way, should I shutdown the TTS on onPause like that? Or just an example?

Comment: onResume/onPause is the safest pair of lifecycle methods to use for  connecting/disconnecting services, registering/unregistering receivers, etc.  Here, they are better than onCreate/onDestroy because you don't need to be connected to TTS when your activity is in the background (not visible).

Answer (score 1):

The reason the method *is* working when clicking on the button is because an event is being fired due to the **onClickListener()** and **onClick()** methods.

Conversely, the line

```
myTTS.speak("Why doesn't this work?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

does not have a listener/method-call that Android can fire. So basically to resolve this you need to call the above method inside an event listener such as **onTouchEvent()** or **onClickListener()**.

Comment: Really appreciate your response! I mean it, but I don't get it.
A button needs a listener because it doesn't know what to do when clicked.
But as for TTS, when I call the method speak(), it just should speak with given arguments because there's all the information, I think.
Sorry for my foolishness.

Answer (score 1):

If you press the `btnSpeak` as fast as you can when the `UI` appears, the `speakOut` method will also fail. You cannot call the `Text To Speech` method `speak` until after `onInit` is called. It is not illegal to call `speak` method before `onInit` but as you can see nothing happens.

Call `speakOut` to speak and enable the `btnSpeak` in `onInit`. If the `bntSpeak` is enable and being pressed before `onInit` is called, nothing will be heard. If the internet is slow this easily happens.

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing that out. "If the internet is slow this easily happens." - Thanks for the information too!